Equivalent to pandas.to_csv() without filename for polars?
Is there an equivalent of casting a Polars DataFrame to a string like for a Pandas DataFrame using pandasdf.to_csv() without an file path ("If None, the result is returned as a string.")?
Similar to this question (How can I cast a Polars DataFrame to string), as a workaround I first cast the Polars DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame and then use to_csv() without a filename, which results the desiread tab delimited string of the whole Pandas DataFrame:
polarsdf.to_pandas().to_csv(sep='\t', index=False)

What I ultimately want to achieve with that is to download the Polars DataFrame in a Shiny for Python app (similar to this question: How to add "download button" in shiny for pandas dataframe)
This I currently achieve using this code:
def download_something():
    yield polarsdf.to_pandas().to_csv(sep='\t', index=False)

If there is a way of doing this without casting the Polars DataFrame to a string, that would also be a sufficient answer to me.

Doesn't it just work like that by default? df.write_csv(separator='\t')

that would be a little embarrassing :D. (for me)

It does indeed and it's also mentioned in the docs. Sorry for that :D. Didn't come to my mind for some reason.

Maybe it's worth answering in your own words - someone else may have the same thought process.

As jqurious suggested the default behavior of Polars write_csv is to cast a Polars df to a string, if not output file is given:
polarsdf.write_csv(separator='\t')

And for Shiny for Python this is my solution now:
def download_something():
    yield polarsdf.write_csv(separator='\t')

